# ifelse command in R not populating column in data frame?

Tags: r

I would appreciate any help with this error I am getting in my code for a research project I am working on in R:

I am trying to create a column (named non_political) in a data frame (named privacy, imported from an sav file) representing survey data where:

- 1 signifies that the respondent was non-political (answered in a non-political way to some questions) and
- 0 signifies the opposite.

So far, I have written:

```
privacy$non_political<-NA

privacy$non_political<-ifelse(((privacy$q19 == 3) | (privacy$q19 == 4) | (privacy$q20 == 2) | (privacy$q21==2)), 1, 0)
```

but

```
head(privacy$non_political)
```

returns NA's along with 1's, which means that the 0 option is never executed in the ifelse command.

What could I be doing wrong here?

Thank you!

Comment: If any of q19, q20, and q21 have missing values, the result will be missing (NA).

Comment: Trying to fix this right now and will report back if it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `==` will generate `NA`'s as output if you have `NA` in your data. You can use `%in%` which will return `FALSE` when comparing with `NA`.

```
privacy$non_political<- with(privacy, 
                        ifelse(q19 %in% c(3, 4) | q20 %in% 2 | q21 %in% 2, 1, 0))
```

You can do this without `ifelse` as well.

```
privacy$non_political<- with(privacy, 
                        as.integer(q19 %in% c(3, 4) | q20 %in% 2 | q21 %in% 2))
```